# Como remover o ponto da casa decimal

Tags: java

Tenho esse metodo

```
   public void calcularVotosTotal(){

    System.out.println("votos valiudos " + this.getNumeroEleitores() * 0.8 + "% " + " Votos Brancos "
                        + this.getNumeroEleitores() * 0.06 + "% " + " votos nulos "
                        +this.getNumeroEleitores() * 0.14 + "% ");
}
```

Tenho aqui o metodo principal

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    AlgoritimoNumeroTotalPessoas antp = new AlgoritimoNumeroTotalPessoas(100);
    antp.totalEleitores();
    antp.calcularVotosTotal();
}
```

e aqui a saída do console abaixo, como faço para remover os pontos na casa decimal? e deixar a saida assim 80%, 6%, 14%

```
Numero total de eleitores 100
votos validos 80.0%  Votos Brancos 6.0%  votos nulos 14.000000000000002%
```

Comment: sei que existem algumas classes como format, BigDecimal, mas nao soube como utilizar nesse estrutura, pois sou iniciante ainda.

Comment: O que o método `getNumeroEleitores` retorna?

Comment: o metodo getNumeroEleitores é so um java bean do atributo numeroEleitores que é do tipo double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deu certo eu tava fazendo o cast de forma errado, obg a todos!

```
public void calcularVotosTotal(){

    System.out.println( "votos validos "  + (int)(this.getNumeroEleitores() *  0.8) + "% " + " Votos Brancos "
                        + (int)(this.getNumeroEleitores() * 0.06) + "% " + " votos nulos "
                        + (int)(this.getNumeroEleitores() *  0.14) + "% ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que vi, você deseja retornar um valor inteiro, acho que o "problema" está no retorno do método `getNumeroEleitores`, que na verdade deveria ser um `long`, imagino que você esteja retornado um `double` ou `float`, nesse caso basta você realizar uma conversão para um `long`, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
public class HelloWorld{
     public static void main(String []args){
        double d = 15.5;
        System.out.println((long) d); //saida: 15
     }
}
```

Obs: Usei o `long` por medo de estourar o valor máximo de `int`.

Comment: fica do mesmo jeito ainda assim

Comment: me mostra como ficou o método `getNumeroEleitores`